# Schengen business visa - when working for 2 companies, do I provide documents for both companies?

Tags: visas, business-travel, nigerian-citizens

I have a business invite for my joint business, where I am the director, from our shipping company in Germany. All expenses will be paid by them. I also work with a second company as well as an employee separately to the first in which I have invite letter for.

Do I need to provide documents showing I work with both companies when going for my visa interview? Last time I got a tourist visa I gave the information as an employee of the second company.

Comment: I have a feeling 'joint going concern business' is not what you mean here, can you elaborate?

Comment: What it is the purpose of your travel? Are you doing business in behave of both companies? Who pay the travel and the expenses? Who pay you during the travel? These are important point to answer your question.

Comment: I am one of the director of the company, registered with CAC and all expense will be paid by the company. However, I am also an employee of another company. the last time I applied for tourist visa which I was given, I gave the information as an employee. Now, I am confused of which document to present at the embassy since I still work as an employee and also manage a company which I got an invite to represent in Germany in July.