# Germany business visa when working for 2 different companies

Tags: nigeria

I am one of the director of the company, registered with CAC and all expense will be paid by the company. However, I am also an employee of another company. the last time I applied for tourist visa which I was given, I gave the information as an employee. Now, I am confused of which document to present at the embassy since I still work as an employee and also manage a company which I got an invite to represent in Germany in July.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135302/schengen-business-visa-when-working-for-2-companies?

Comment: In general the advice given on this site is to tell the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question without answers.